# How to render an entry template in plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a section "Emails" which has an entry 'Welcome Email'. The template assigned for it under Section is '_email/welcome'. This works fine when viewed in frontend. But I want to render the same template in my plugin services. The code I have used is:

```
$template = 'welcome';
$data = 'foo';

$oldPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();
$path = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath().'_email/';
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($path);
$html = craft()->templates->render($template,$data);
$breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
$text = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $html);
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($oldPath);
```

But this gives an error "_email/_layout" not found in craft.log . What am I doing wrong ? Could anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a frontend request

```
$html = craft()->templates->render('_emails/_layout.twig', $data);
```

and in a backend request

```
$oldPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();
$newPath = craft()->path->getSiteTemplatesPath();
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($newPath);
$html = craft()->templates->render('_emails/_layout.twig', array());
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($oldPath);
```

Comment: For backend request it Still gives same error `exception.Craft\TemplateLoaderException] exception 'Craft\TemplateLoaderException' with message 'Unable to find the template “_emails/_layout.twig”.' in /..path../craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php:123`

Comment: And your template is a `.twig` file and in `/_emails/_layout.twig`? Because it works for me and it always has. Could you dump the `$newPath` and check if it's correct?

Comment: Everything was correct but still things were not working. But strangely after clearing out cache your code worked. Thanks.